# No Bluetooth found and speakers don't work on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my Chuwi lapbook and everything seems to be working except for two things.

(1) It doesn't recognize that the laptop has Bluetooth, prompting me with the message:

```
no bluetooth found plug in a dongle to use bluetooth
```

(2) The other issue is that the speakers don't seem to work. I've installed the PulseAudio volume control.  It recognizes the speakers and shows that sound is playing, but no sound is coming out of the actual speakers. When I use headphones, everything works normally though.

Any suggestions?